# Firebase image upload failing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image for an user when he creates an account but account is being created but the image isn't getting uploaded,not even the folder images/ is being created in the firebase.I have tried several methods to upload an image but nothing helps .Sharing the code below :

class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var picBtn : ImageView
private var filePath: Uri? = null
private val PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 22
var storage: FirebaseStorage? = null
var storageReference: StorageReference? = null



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)
    getSupportActionBar()?.hide()

    val signupBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signup_btn)
    auth = Firebase.auth
    picBtn = findViewById(R.id.pro_pick_btn)

                                //Profile Picture Selection

    picBtn.setOnClickListener{
        SelectImage()
    }

                                //Signup Procedure

    signupBtn.setOnClickListener {


                                    //Hide Keyboard and Button
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)



        var fname = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.f_name).text.toString().trim()
        var lname = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.l_name).text.toString().trim()
        var email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.reg_email).text.toString().trim()
        var pswd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.reg_pswd).text.toString().trim()
        var cpswd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.reg_cpswd).text.toString().trim()


                                            //Full Auth Process
        if ((pswd == cpswd) && (fname != "") && (lname != "") && (pswd != "") && (email != "")){
            signupBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
                                            //Progress Bar
            val transactionProgress = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transactionProgress.setTransition(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE)
            transactionProgress.add(R.id.progressContainer, ProgressView(), "Progress Bar").commit()

                                            //Authentication Process
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pswd)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this@RegistrationActivity) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success")
                        val user = auth.currentUser
                        uploadImage()
                        updateUI(user)
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        updateUI(null)
                    }
                }
    }
        else if( (pswd != cpswd) && (fname != "") && (lname != "") && (pswd != "") && (email != "")){
            Toast.makeText(this@RegistrationActivity, "Please enter a matching Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this@RegistrationActivity, "Enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

private fun uploadImage() {
    if (filePath != null) {

        // Code for showing progressDialog while uploading
        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...")
        progressDialog.show()

        // Defining the child of storageReference

        val ref: StorageReference? =  storageReference?.child(
                "images/"
                        + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            )

        // adding listeners on upload
        // or failure of image
        ref?.putFile(filePath!!)
            ?.addOnSuccessListener { // Image uploaded successfully
                // Dismiss dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast
                    .makeText(
                        this@RegistrationActivity,
                        "Image Uploaded!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    .show()
                Log.d("Anandhu:","Good going")
            }
            ?.addOnFailureListener { e -> // Error, Image not uploaded
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast
                    .makeText(
                        this@RegistrationActivity,
                        "Failed " + e.message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    .show()
                Log.d("Anandhu:","Bad going")
            }
            ?.addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot ->

                // Progress Listener for loading
                // percentage on the dialog box
                val progress = (100.0
                        * taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred
                        / taskSnapshot.totalByteCount)
                progressDialog.setMessage(
                    "Uploaded "
                            + progress.toInt() + "%"
                )
                Log.d("Anandhu:"," going")
            }
    }
}


private fun SelectImage() {

    // Defining Implicit Intent to mobile gallery
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(
            intent,
            "Select Image from here..."
        ),
        PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST
    )
}

// Override onActivityResult method
override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {
    super.onActivityResult(
        requestCode,
        resultCode,
        data
    )

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.data != null) {

        // Get the Uri of data
        filePath = data.data
        try {

            // Setting image on image view using Bitmap
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                .getBitmap(
                    contentResolver,
                    filePath
                )
            val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
            picBtn.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Log the exception
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}



//Forward Function
private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
    val loginIntent = Intent(this@RegistrationActivity,LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(loginIntent)
    finish()
}
```

}

Comment: What do your security rules for firebae storage look like?

Comment: Are you able to see image on you UI?

Comment: `var filePath: Uri? = null` Please name it `var fileUri: Uri? = null` as an uri is no path.

Comment: `ref?.putFile(filePath!!)` You cannot use an uri there. It should be a path.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexanderN. I havent set any security rules for firebase

Comment: @PriyankaSinghal , Yeah I am able to see image after choosing it from gallery,But its not getting updated in database